# Google Tango: unable to get path for dataset UUID

Tags: google-project-tango

I am developing an app using Google Tango (with Lenovo Phab 2 Pro). I am trying to generate a floorplan from a Tango dataset. I made sure the user provides the following permissions: `Tango.PERMISSIONTYPE_DATASET` and `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. The dataset recording mode is `TangoConfig.TANGO_DATASETRECORDING_MODE_SCENE_RECONSTRUCTION`. The datasets path is kept to the default: `TangoDataset.TANGO_DEFAULT_EXPORT_DIRECTORY`.

After checking with `adb` I see the dataset being there, but if I try to create a floorplan with the following code, I get an error.

```
Tango3dReconstructionConfig config = new Tango3dReconstructionConfig();
config.putBoolean(Tango3dReconstructionConfig.USE_SPACE_CLEARING, true);
config.putBoolean("use_floorplan", true);
config.putBoolean("use_floorplan_canonical_orientation", true);

Tango3dReconstruction mTango3dReconstruction = new Tango3dReconstruction(config);
TangoDataset dataset = new TangoDataset(TangoDataset.TANGO_DEFAULT_EXPORT_DIRECTORY,
    mTango.experimentalGetCurrentDatasetUuid());

Tango3dReconstructionAreaDescription areaDescription =
        Tango3dReconstructionAreaDescription.createFromDataset(dataset, null, null);
```

The error that I get:

> E/tango: tango_java_dataset_api.cc:155 unable to get path for dataset UUID: 079c4703-3ad7-2e5b-89a1-66ce3a37bc78

Any idea what is going wrong? Do you know of any existing examples using datasets?

**EDIT:** I tried the same thing using the C API. The error I get now is:

> geo_location.cc:53 Calibration file /storage/emulated/0/Tango/datasets/fe520387-53ca-264d-9043-705a9d03c25e//online-calibration.xml does not exist
>   So I guess I will have do something about calibration in order to make sure this file gets generated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what do you know! I had to add a trailing slash to the base directory and it worked. Like this:

```
TangoDataset dataset = new TangoDataset(
    TangoDataset.TANGO_DEFAULT_EXPORT_DIRECTORY + File.separator,
    mTango.experimentalGetCurrentDatasetUuid());
```